# Need to make a DIV appear as a floating footer that will remain in front of an iframe when the window is resized

Tags: css, html, iframe

I've been stuck on this for days. I have a page where the central view is an iframe. There is a top row of link buttons above the iframe, and a bottom row of link buttons below the iframe. I have been trying to get the top and bottom button bars to hug the top and bottom of the window, even when it is resized. I've gotten to that point, but the bottom link bar remains behind the iframe 100% of the time. I've tried positioning, z-index, jquery...I am completely stumped. Here is the code, with links subtracted (classified links). Also, it's SharePoint Designer 2010 I'm working on.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<%@ Page Language="C#" %>
<%@ Register Tagprefix="SharePoint" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %>
<html dir="ltr" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:mso="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:msdt="uuid:C2F41010-65B3-11d1-A29F-00AA00C14882">

<%@ Register Tagprefix="SharePoint" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %>
<head runat="server">
<meta name="WebPartPageExpansion" content="full" />
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>UNIT DASHBOARD</title>

<style type="text/css">
.CAATDashboardTable {
background-image: url('#');
background-repeat: repeat;
background-position: 0px 0px;
width: 750px;
padding-left: 1px;
border-collapse:collapse;
}
td.buttonItemWhite {
                height: 53px;
                width:174px;
                padding-left:0px;
                padding-right:0px;
                text-align:center;
                vertical-align:middle;
                background-position:2px, 0, 0, 0;
                cursor:hand;
}
</style>
</head>
<!--START CLASSIFICATION BANNER-->
<div name="bannertable" id="bannertable" style="position:fixed, top=100px, left=0px; width:100%; background-image:url('/PublishingImages/BannerGrad.gif'); background-repeat: repeat y; color: red">
    <table  border="0" width="100%" id="table1">
        <tr style="font-size:8pt">
            <td style="font-family:microsoft sans serif,lucinda sans,impact,arial black,arial;font-weight:bold; color:#ffffff;text-align:center">
            CLASSIFICATION</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
<!--END  BANNER-->

<body>


<div class="ddoverlap">


<table align="center" cellpadding="0" class="CAATDashboardTable" cellspacing="0" xmlns:x="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/dsp" xmlns:asp="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ASPNET/20" xmlns:__designer="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebParts/v2/DataView/designer" xmlns:SharePoint="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls" xmlns:ddwrt2="urn:frontpage:internal" style="width: 100%">                       
<tr>
<td style="height: 65px; width: 100%;">

<!--BELOW TABLE CONTAINS THE TOP BORDER LINKS-->

<table style="width: 100%" align="center"><tr>

<td title="S-3 TOC Update Slide" style="background-position: center 0px; background-image:url('#'); background-repeat: no-repeat; color: #FFFFFF;" class="buttonItemWhite" 
onclick="&#xD;&#xA;window.open('#','target1');&#xD;&#xA;
" onmouseover="&#xD;&#xA;this.style.backgroundImage = 'url(&quot;'#';)';&#xD;&#xA;
" onmouseout="&#xD;&#xA;this.style.backgroundImage = 'url(&quot;'#'&quot;)';&#xD;&#xA;">
<a title="S-3 TOC Update Slide"><strong>S-3</strong></a></td>

<td title="SWO Weather Update" style="background-position: center 0px; background-image:url('#'); background-repeat: no-repeat; color: #FFFFFF;" class="buttonItemWhite" 
onclick="&#xD;&#xA;window.open('#','target1');&#xD;&#xA;
" onmouseover="&#xD;&#xA;this.style.backgroundImage = 'url(&quot;'#'&quot;)';&#xD;&#xA;
" onmouseout="&#xD;&#xA;this.style.backgroundImage = 'url(&quot;'#'&quot;)';&#xD;&#xA;">
<a title="SWO Weather Update"><strong>Weather</strong></a></td>

<td title="S-3 TOC Update Slide" style="background-position: center 0px; background-image:url('#'); background-repeat: no-repeat; color: #FFFFFF;" class="buttonItemWhite" 
onclick="&#xD;&#xA;window.open('#','target1');&#xD;&#xA;
" onmouseover="&#xD;&#xA;this.style.backgroundImage = 'url(&quot;'#';)';&#xD;&#xA;
" onmouseout="&#xD;&#xA;this.style.backgroundImage = 'url(&quot;'#'&quot;)';&#xD;&#xA;">
<a title="S-3 TOC Update Slide"><strong>S-3</strong></a></td>

<td title="S-3 TOC Update Slide" style="background-position: center 0px; background-image:url('#'); background-repeat: no-repeat; color: #FFFFFF;" class="buttonItemWhite" 
onclick="&#xD;&#xA;window.open('#','target1');&#xD;&#xA;
" onmouseover="&#xD;&#xA;this.style.backgroundImage = 'url(&quot;'#';)';&#xD;&#xA;
" onmouseout="&#xD;&#xA;this.style.backgroundImage = 'url(&quot;'#'&quot;)';&#xD;&#xA;">
<a title="S-3 TOC Update Slide"><strong>S-3</strong></a></td>

<td title="S-3 TOC Update Slide" style="background-position: center 0px; background-image:url('#'); background-repeat: no-repeat; color: #FFFFFF;" class="buttonItemWhite" 
onclick="&#xD;&#xA;window.open('#','target1');&#xD;&#xA;
" onmouseover="&#xD;&#xA;this.style.backgroundImage = 'url(&quot;'#';)';&#xD;&#xA;
" onmouseout="&#xD;&#xA;this.style.backgroundImage = 'url(&quot;'#'&quot;)';&#xD;&#xA;">
<a title="S-3 TOC Update Slide"><strong>S-3</strong></a></td>

<td title="S-3 TOC Update Slide" style="background-position: center 0px; background-image:url('#'); background-repeat: no-repeat; color: #FFFFFF;" class="buttonItemWhite" 
onclick="&#xD;&#xA;window.open('#','target1');&#xD;&#xA;
" onmouseover="&#xD;&#xA;this.style.backgroundImage = 'url(&quot;'#';)';&#xD;&#xA;
" onmouseout="&#xD;&#xA;this.style.backgroundImage = 'url(&quot;'#'&quot;)';&#xD;&#xA;">
<a title="S-3 TOC Update Slide"><strong>S-3</strong></a></td>

<td title="S-3 TOC Update Slide" style="background-position: center 0px; background-image:url('#'); background-repeat: no-repeat; color: #FFFFFF;" class="buttonItemWhite" 
onclick="&#xD;&#xA;window.open('#','target1');&#xD;&#xA;
" onmouseover="&#xD;&#xA;this.style.backgroundImage = 'url(&quot;'#';)';&#xD;&#xA;
" onmouseout="&#xD;&#xA;this.style.backgroundImage = 'url(&quot;'#'&quot;)';&#xD;&#xA;">
<a title="S-3 TOC Update Slide"><strong>S-3</strong></a></td>


<td title="S-3 TOC Update Slide" style="background-position: center 0px; background-image:url('#'); background-repeat: no-repeat; color: #FFFFFF;" class="buttonItemWhite" 
onclick="&#xD;&#xA;window.open('#','target1');&#xD;&#xA;
" onmouseover="&#xD;&#xA;this.style.backgroundImage = 'url(&quot;'#';)';&#xD;&#xA;
" onmouseout="&#xD;&#xA;this.style.backgroundImage = 'url(&quot;'#'&quot;)';&#xD;&#xA;">
<a title="S-3 TOC Update Slide"><strong>S-3</strong></a></td>

<td title="S-3 TOC Update Slide" style="background-position: center 0px; background-image:url('#'); background-repeat: no-repeat; color: #FFFFFF;" class="buttonItemWhite" 
onclick="&#xD;&#xA;window.open('#','target1');&#xD;&#xA;
" onmouseover="&#xD;&#xA;this.style.backgroundImage = 'url(&quot;'#';)';&#xD;&#xA;
" onmouseout="&#xD;&#xA;this.style.backgroundImage = 'url(&quot;'#'&quot;)';&#xD;&#xA;">
<a title="S-3 TOC Update Slide"><strong>S-3</strong></a></td>

<td title="S-3 TOC Update Slide" style="background-position: center 0px; background-image:url('#'); background-repeat: no-repeat; color: #FFFFFF;" class="buttonItemWhite" 
onclick="&#xD;&#xA;window.open('#','target1');&#xD;&#xA;
" onmouseover="&#xD;&#xA;this.style.backgroundImage = 'url(&quot;'#';)';&#xD;&#xA;
" onmouseout="&#xD;&#xA;this.style.backgroundImage = 'url(&quot;'#'&quot;)';&#xD;&#xA;">
<a title="S-3 TOC Update Slide"><strong>S-3</strong></a></td>



</td></tr>
</table>

</div>

<iframe name="target1" width="100%" src="#" frameborder="0" style="height: 785px"></iframe>


<table align="center" cellpadding="0" class="CAATDashboardTable" cellspacing="0" xmlns:x="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/dsp" xmlns:asp="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ASPNET/20" xmlns:__designer="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebParts/v2/DataView/designer" xmlns:SharePoint="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls" xmlns:ddwrt2="urn:frontpage:internal" style="width: 100%">                       
<tr>
<td style="height: 65px; width: 100%;">

<!--BELOW TABLE CONTAINS THE BOTTOM BORDER LINKS-->

<table style="width: 100%" align="center"><tr>

<td title="S-3 TOC Update Slide" style="background-position: center 0px; background-image:url('#'); background-repeat: no-repeat; color: #FFFFFF;" class="buttonItemWhite" 
onclick="&#xD;&#xA;window.open('#','target1');&#xD;&#xA;
" onmouseover="&#xD;&#xA;this.style.backgroundImage = 'url(&quot;'#';)';&#xD;&#xA;
" onmouseout="&#xD;&#xA;this.style.backgroundImage = 'url(&quot;'#'&quot;)';&#xD;&#xA;">
<a title="S-3 TOC Update Slide"><strong>S-3</strong></a></td>

<td title="S-3 TOC Update Slide" style="background-position: center 0px; background-image:url('#'); background-repeat: no-repeat; color: #FFFFFF;" class="buttonItemWhite" 
onclick="&#xD;&#xA;window.open('#','target1');&#xD;&#xA;
" onmouseover="&#xD;&#xA;this.style.backgroundImage = 'url(&quot;'#';)';&#xD;&#xA;
" onmouseout="&#xD;&#xA;this.style.backgroundImage = 'url(&quot;'#'&quot;)';&#xD;&#xA;">
<a title="S-3 TOC Update Slide"><strong>S-3</strong></a></td>

<td title="S-3 TOC Update Slide" style="background-position: center 0px; background-image:url('#'); background-repeat: no-repeat; color: #FFFFFF;" class="buttonItemWhite" 
onclick="&#xD;&#xA;window.open('#','target1');&#xD;&#xA;
" onmouseover="&#xD;&#xA;this.style.backgroundImage = 'url(&quot;'#';)';&#xD;&#xA;
" onmouseout="&#xD;&#xA;this.style.backgroundImage = 'url(&quot;'#'&quot;)';&#xD;&#xA;">
<a title="S-3 TOC Update Slide"><strong>S-3</strong></a></td>

<td title="S-3 TOC Update Slide" style="background-position: center 0px; background-image:url('#'); background-repeat: no-repeat; color: #FFFFFF;" class="buttonItemWhite" 
onclick="&#xD;&#xA;window.open('#','target1');&#xD;&#xA;
" onmouseover="&#xD;&#xA;this.style.backgroundImage = 'url(&quot;'#';)';&#xD;&#xA;
" onmouseout="&#xD;&#xA;this.style.backgroundImage = 'url(&quot;'#'&quot;)';&#xD;&#xA;">
<a title="S-3 TOC Update Slide"><strong>S-3</strong></a></td>


<td title="S-3 TOC Update Slide" style="background-position: center 0px; background-image:url('#'); background-repeat: no-repeat; color: #FFFFFF;" class="buttonItemWhite" 
onclick="&#xD;&#xA;window.open('#','target1');&#xD;&#xA;
" onmouseover="&#xD;&#xA;this.style.backgroundImage = 'url(&quot;'#';)';&#xD;&#xA;
" onmouseout="&#xD;&#xA;this.style.backgroundImage = 'url(&quot;'#'&quot;)';&#xD;&#xA;">
<a title="S-3 TOC Update Slide"><strong>S-3</strong></a></td>


<td title="S-3 TOC Update Slide" style="background-position: center 0px; background-image:url('#'); background-repeat: no-repeat; color: #FFFFFF;" class="buttonItemWhite" 
onclick="&#xD;&#xA;window.open('#','target1');&#xD;&#xA;
" onmouseover="&#xD;&#xA;this.style.backgroundImage = 'url(&quot;'#';)';&#xD;&#xA;
" onmouseout="&#xD;&#xA;this.style.backgroundImage = 'url(&quot;'#'&quot;)';&#xD;&#xA;">
<a title="S-3 TOC Update Slide"><strong>S-3</strong></a></td>

<td title="S-3 TOC Update Slide" style="background-position: center 0px; background-image:url('#'); background-repeat: no-repeat; color: #FFFFFF;" class="buttonItemWhite" 
onclick="&#xD;&#xA;window.open('#','target1');&#xD;&#xA;
" onmouseover="&#xD;&#xA;this.style.backgroundImage = 'url(&quot;'#';)';&#xD;&#xA;
" onmouseout="&#xD;&#xA;this.style.backgroundImage = 'url(&quot;'#'&quot;)';&#xD;&#xA;">
<a title="S-3 TOC Update Slide"><strong>S-3</strong></a></td>


<td title="S-3 TOC Update Slide" style="background-position: center 0px; background-image:url('#'); background-repeat: no-repeat; color: #FFFFFF;" class="buttonItemWhite" 
onclick="&#xD;&#xA;window.open('#','target1');&#xD;&#xA;
" onmouseover="&#xD;&#xA;this.style.backgroundImage = 'url(&quot;'#';)';&#xD;&#xA;
" onmouseout="&#xD;&#xA;this.style.backgroundImage = 'url(&quot;'#'&quot;)';&#xD;&#xA;">
<a title="S-3 TOC Update Slide"><strong>S-3</strong></a></td>

<td title="S-3 TOC Update Slide" style="background-position: center 0px; background-image:url('#'); background-repeat: no-repeat; color: #FFFFFF;" class="buttonItemWhite" 
onclick="&#xD;&#xA;window.open('#','target1');&#xD;&#xA;
" onmouseover="&#xD;&#xA;this.style.backgroundImage = 'url(&quot;'#';)';&#xD;&#xA;
" onmouseout="&#xD;&#xA;this.style.backgroundImage = 'url(&quot;'#'&quot;)';&#xD;&#xA;">
<a title="S-3 TOC Update Slide"><strong>S-3</strong></a></td>

<td title="S-3 TOC Update Slide" style="background-position: center 0px; background-image:url('#'); background-repeat: no-repeat; color: #FFFFFF;" class="buttonItemWhite" 
onclick="&#xD;&#xA;window.open('#','target1');&#xD;&#xA;
" onmouseover="&#xD;&#xA;this.style.backgroundImage = 'url(&quot;'#';)';&#xD;&#xA;
" onmouseout="&#xD;&#xA;this.style.backgroundImage = 'url(&quot;'#'&quot;)';&#xD;&#xA;">
<a title="S-3 TOC Update Slide"><strong>S-3</strong></a></td>

<td title="S-3 TOC Update Slide" style="background-position: center 0px; background-image:url('#'); background-repeat: no-repeat; color: #FFFFFF;" class="buttonItemWhite" 
onclick="&#xD;&#xA;window.open('#','target1');&#xD;&#xA;
" onmouseover="&#xD;&#xA;this.style.backgroundImage = 'url(&quot;'#';)';&#xD;&#xA;
" onmouseout="&#xD;&#xA;this.style.backgroundImage = 'url(&quot;'#'&quot;)';&#xD;&#xA;">
<a title="S-3 TOC Update Slide"><strong>S-3</strong></a></td>



</td></tr>
</table>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure this is what your asking but you can't show anything on top of an iframe I don't think, definitely not cross browser. But I doubt you need to.

Now first off, your HTML seems improper because you open a `<div class="ddoverlap">`, then a `<table>`, then *another* `<table>` which contains the links. You close that **2nd** `<table>` and then try to close the `<div>` while your still inside of the **1st** `<table>`:

```
<div class="ddoverlap">

  <!-- 1st table -->
  <table align="center" cellpadding="0" class="CAATDashboardTable" cellspacing="0" xmlns:x="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/dsp" xmlns:asp="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ASPNET/20" xmlns:__designer="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebParts/v2/DataView/designer" xmlns:SharePoint="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls" xmlns:ddwrt2="urn:frontpage:internal" style="width: 100%">                       
    <tr>
      <td style="height: 65px; width: 100%;">

        <!--BELOW TABLE CONTAINS THE TOP BORDER LINKS-->

        <table style="width: 100%" align="center"><tr> <!-- 2nd table! -->

          <!-- (content omitted to uncover document structure) -->

          </td></tr> <!-- (also this </td> is double) -->

        </table> <!-- closing 2nd table -->
  <!-- Not closing 1st table -->
</div>
```

So advice to you would be to recheck your HTML first of all. Then you have a couple of options. The simplest is to continue using a `<table>` for mark-up. This is considered a bad habit nowadays, but so is using `<iframe>` and you're probably stuck with that.

When using `<table>` for mark-up, make it 1 big table that stretches across the available screenspace and put the `<iframe>` inside. This way the `<iframe>` will simply stretch to the size of the `<td>` it's inside. So a rough doc structure would be:

```
<table style="width:100%;height:100%;">
  <tr>
    <!-- the <td>s with the links, I've counted, both top and bottom are 10 -->
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="10" style="width:100%;height:100%">
      <iframe name="target1" width="100%" height="100%" src="#" frameborder="0"></iframe>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <!-- the <td>s with the links, again 10 -->
  </tr>
</table>
```

Notice the `colspan="10"` to have the `<td>` with the `<iframe>` stretch the width of the 10  cells in the top and bottom.

*Edit:* A non-table way of doing this would be with `<div>` and `CSS`. With different numbers of buttons at the top and bottom, it might be something like this:

```
<head>
  <style type="text/css">
    #topbar, #bottombar {
      position:absolute;
      width:100%;
      height:1.2em;
    }
    #topbar {
      top:0;
    }
    #bottombar {
      bottom:0;
    }
    iframe {
      position:absolute;
      top:1.2em;
      bottom:1.2em;
      width:100%;
    }
    #topbar a {
      display:inline-block;
      width:10%; /* 100/10=10 */
    }
    #bottombar a {
      display:inline-block;
      width:9%;  /* 100/11~=9 */
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="topbar">
    <a onclick="blablablayougetthepoint">Something</a>
    <!-- more links, total of 10, notice the onclick is now on the a, no more td -->
  </div>
  <div id="bottombar">
    <a onclick="yadayadayada">Some other thing</a>
    <!-- more links, total of 11 -->
  </div>
  <iframe src="etc"></iframe>
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks...I'll try it out. I should have mentioned that I'm pulling from a bunch of already created pages, and I'm an HTML novice. Also, I have no server-side access for SharePoint.

Comment: It worked. You are a lifesaver. I wasted so much time banging away on that, and it was just an issue of crappy HTML work. Another question...in the event that I have to add new buttons to the bar and the result is an uneven number of buttons: can you recommend a good way to make the button bars auto fit to the table width? Right now I've got 11 links on the bottom, and the 11th link juts out to the right.

Comment: Just increase the value I set for `colspan` to match the amount of buttons. So `colspan="11"` in that case.

Comment: When I do that, the iframe stretches out to span 11 buttons, but there is a gap in the top on the right from where there isn't an 11th button. In the spirit of trying to follow your "try not to use tables" advice...is there a better way to segment off the button rows so that they auto stretch to fit the width even if there are, for example, 8 buttons on top and 12 on the bottom? I have a very high maintenance boss...

Comment: Kudos for having to deal with high maintenance bosses ;) I added the non-table way of doing it, at least my best effort.

Comment: It works, but it's not picking up on the background image, no matter where I put it in the CSS. I'm sticking with the table version for now, but I've got the other page as a work in progress. Thanks for the help!